# Android NIO Channel byteBuffer is empty on receiver

Tags: android, nio, channel, bytebuffer

I'm running into an issue where I'm opening a local file on my Android device and I'm trying to send it to another device that's listening on a port. It's sending the information (I see data in mappedByteBuffer). However, when the data is received on the listener and I view byteBuffer, the data is all blank. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Sender:**

```
WritableByteChannel channel;
FileChannel fic;
long fsize;
ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer;

connection = new Socket(Resource.LAN_IP_ADDRESS, Resource.LAN_SOCKET_PORT); 
out = connection.getOutputStream(); 
File f = new File(filename);

in = new FileInputStream(f);
fic = in.getChannel();
fsize = fic.size();
channel = Channels.newChannel(out); 

//other code    

//Send file
long currPos = 0;
while (currPos < fsize)
{
    if (fsize - currPos < Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE)
    {                       
        mappedByteBuffer = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currPos, fsize - currPos);
        channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);
        currPos = fsize;
    }
    else
    {
        mappedByteBuffer = fic.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, currPos, Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
        channel.write(mappedByteBuffer);
        currPos += Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE;
    }
}

closeAllConnections(); //closes connection, fic, channel, in, out
```

**Listener**

```
FileChannel foc;
ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
ReadableByteChannel channel;

serverSoc = new ServerSocket(myPort);
connection = serverSoc.accept(); 
connection.setSoTimeout(3600000);
connection.setReceiveBufferSize(Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
in = connection.getInputStream();
out = new FileOutputStream(new File(currentFileName));
foc = out.getChannel();
channel = Channels.newChannel(in); 

//other code        

while (fileSize > 0)
{
    if (fileSize < Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE)
    {
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate((int)fileSize);
        channel.read(byteBuffer); 
        //byteBuffer is blank!
        foc.write(byteBuffer);
        fileSize = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE);
        channel.read(byteBuffer);
        //byteBuffer is blank!                         
        foc.write(byteBuffer);
        fileSize -= Resource.MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE;
    }
}

closeAllConnections(); //closes connection, foc, channel, in, out, serverSoc
```

**Note:**
MEMORY_ALLOC_SIZE = 32768

Comment: I believe the problem is needing the rewind method call. I restructured my listener to do the following, and I believe it is working now: 
    byteBuffer.rewind(); 
    channel.read(byteBuffer); 
    byteBuffer.rewind(); 
    foc.write(byteBuffer);

Answer (score 0):

Found the best way to write to the channels this way is the following (don't use my original way, it produces missing characters and extra spaces):

```
while (channel.read(byteBuffer) != -1) 
{  
    byteBuffer.flip();  
    foc.write(byteBuffer);  
    byteBuffer.compact();  
}

byteBuffer.flip();  
while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) 
{  
    foc.write(byteBuffer);  
}
```